# How do I retrieve a path's data from firebase database using python?

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

I have this firebase database structure

[image]

I want to print out the inventory list(Inventory) for each ID under Businesses.
So I tried this code

```
db = firebase.database() 
all_users = db.child("Businesses").get()
for user in all_users.each():
    userid = user.key()
    inventorydb = db.child("Businesses").child(userid).child("Inventory")
    print(inventorydb)
```

but all I got is this

```
  <pyrebase.pyrebase.Database object at 0x1091eada0>
```

what am I doing wrong and how can I loop through each Business ID and print out their inventory?

Comment: You printed a database object. You can see it's functions using `dir(inventorydb)` , or go find the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're printing a Database object. You need to get the data still.

You seem to already know how to get that as well as the children. <sub>Or you only copied the examples without understanding it...</sub>

Either way, you can try this

```
db = firebase.database() 
businesses = db.child("Businesses")
for userid in businesses.shallow().get().each():
    inventory = businesses.child(userid).child("Inventory").get()
    print( inventory.val() )
```

On a side note, `National_Stock_Numbers` looks like it should be a value of the name, not a key for a child

Comment: thanks, can userid be used prior to it been defined?

Comment: It's defined by the loop. I don't understand the question