# How to give each request a sequential ID in android application?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know this question may seem ambiguous to many users, but I'll try to elaborate the question in brief. I'm trying to build an object recognition application through android. The photo captured by the camera will be send to firebase database and from there the photo will be fetched by python script and recognition of image will be done. So my question is how can I code for an application which will push image from application to the database such as key of captured images by user(any application user) will be in sequence:

> image1, image2, image3....

It implies that if *'a'* user capture an image, photo will be uploaded to database with key 'image**1**'. After when user *'b'* takes a photo, image will be pushed with the key 'image**2**'. Note that the application can be used by number of users simultaneously. So any suggestions on how should I implement this in android?

Comment: You should avoid any requirement like this, it will only become a problem as you scale.  Generating the id will become your bottleneck.  Use UUIDs instead.

Comment: Then how can I decide in Python, which image to be taken from database? Because python gives really small number of functionalities regarding firebase

Comment: Downvoter can you give me a reason to downvote the question?

Comment: @HrishikeshKulkarni check my answer I think it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, authenticate the user then get the `id` of each user and store in the database that way its easier to retrieve later on.

like this:-

```
DatabaseReference ref = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

Firebase user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

//to send to database
ref.child("uid").setValue(user.getUID());
```

Now you have the `userid` under `users`, then under `userid` add an image.

So example:

```
  {
  "users":{
     "userid":{
         "name": "peter"
         "image": "link_from_storage"
  }
 }
}
```

This way everytime a user captures an image he will have a userid for him.
Now for the image, you have to send it to the `firebase storage` and then take the link from there and store it in the database.

Example:

```
  StorageReference filepath=mStorage.child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

  filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new 
  OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
   @Override                                                                         
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

String downloaduri=taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

Basically the first line, you are adding the image to the firebase storage.Then you do a listener to get the image `url` from storage and put it in `downloaduri`.

Then to add image in database:-

```
ref.child("image").setValue(downloaduri);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Fairly agree with your answer @Peter Haddad. But the problem is about retrieving these uploaded image through Python. Python gives only functionality of reading particular value of corresponding key. You're suggesting to put UID as key(which we usually do in Android). Then how can I determine which "key" to be read in Python(Since python will not be known about any user id)?

Comment: cant you loop through the userid?@HrishikeshKulkarni, or do you want a random id of each image?

Comment: No I want image-id as image1, image2, image3 like this. And there's no possibility of looping through children of corresponding parent in Python, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46136180/how-do-i-retrieve-a-paths-data-from-firebase-database-using-python might help you @HrishikeshKulkarni

Answer (score 1):

The last time I used firebase was about 8-10 months back so I do not remember the syntaxes.

You can use Firebase's [could storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/) to upload your images to cloud when users upload it. You can generate an id (`key`) accordingly and save it in the database with the reference to that image as the `value` to that `key`. You can read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) how to do that.

Fortunately, Firebase [functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) can then be used with the Cloud storage to access and process the image. You just need to read about [Cloud storage triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events).

Comment: But there's no way to handle firebase cloud storage through android! :(

Comment: My bad, spell mistake. I wanted to say there's no way to handle firebase cloud through "Python"

Answer (score 1):

> you have to maintain some thing like this if im not wrong

1. Place holder folder image in firebase file system.
2. Place holder forder image_name, uploaded user_name(if required based on your needs) and time_stamp at what time uploaded.
3. Now first fetch the image_names, with timestamps and then based time stamp fetch images files.